# How to bind byte array as image in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, database, image, xaml, data-binding

Im very new to this site. Its my first question! hope somone knows the answer.

Here is the deal, I have a database with entities that hold a byte array as a picture (one of the entity properties).
here is the code that convets the pic to byte[] before saving it to the DB:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ImageFileToByteArrayAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
    return pixelData.DetachPixelData();
}
```

when I pull the entity from the database I see that it comes with the correct data of the picture as byte[].

Im working on a windows 8.1 app and with mvvmCross. in my viewModel I have a full prop named selectedGuest. this property holds the current Guest. all the info about the guest is succsessfuly transformed to the UI accept the image! here is the xaml of the image:

```
 <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding SelectedGuest.Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageConverter}}"/>
```

and here is the converter:

```
public class ByteArrayToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is byte[]))
            return null;

        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes((byte[])value);
                writer.StoreAsync().GetResults();
            }
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
            image.DecodePixelWidth = 150;
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

when debuging the thread ENTERS the converter and the 'value' is correct! but somhow I cant see the image. nothing apears, the image just wont display.

thanks for the viewers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the original encoded image buffer (i.e. the binary image file content) in your database, not the raw pixel data:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ImageFileToByteArrayAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
    return buffer.ToArray();
}
```